# How do you use a sub slice with scanning hexadecimal strings with Sscanf?

Tags: go

I have a parsing function that will fill a byte array with data given in a string format.

```
func Parse(data string) ([]byte, error) {
    bs := make([]byte, 6)

    // Create sub slices over larger slice
    a := bs[0:2]
    b := bs[2:4]
    c := bs[4:6]

    // Attempt to scan each string value into their respective slices
    _, err := fmt.Sscanf(data, "%4x-%4x-%4x", &a, &b, &c)

    return bs, err
}
```

Evaluating this function on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/c0o9mjIqlg) the null value of the byte array is returned.

```
func main() {
    d, err := Parse("00ff-ff00-00ff")
    fmt.Printf("Value: %+v Error: %s\n", d, err)
}
```

Which yields:

```
Value: [0 0 0 0 0 0] Error: %!s(<nil>)
```

I expected the above approach to return `[0 255 255 0 0 255]`. Is there a correct approach to populating a byte array with data using Sscanf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `Sscanf` it will re-allocate the pointers for `a`, `b`, and `c` so that they no longer point to their respective locations within `bs`. You'll see this if you output the values of these variables:

```
fmt.Printf("%v %v %v", a, b, c)
# Outputs [0 255] [255 0] [0 255]
```

You can return the result like this:

```
result := append(a, b...)
result = append(result, c...)
return result, nil
```

Comment: It *is* a reference to the underlying array. https://play.golang.org/p/EQDfsMq9SB

Comment: @noisypixy This is my confusion. I thought a slice referenced the underlying array that is created with the initial make call. I can certainly print  the sub slices as suggested above, but the underlying array remains unchanged.

Comment: Interesting, I guess `Sscanf` is doing some re-allocations internally. Updated answer.

Comment: Extending @noisypixy's example reveals that `Sscanf` must allocate a new byte array and update the pointer referenced by `a` to the new allocation. https://play.golang.org/p/Ai2E6ZsMZc

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result that you expected, and by nearly identical means as you originally attempted. This modified version of your example yields `Value: [0 255 255 0 0 255] Error: <nil>`:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func parse(data string) ([]byte, error) {
    bs := make([]byte, 6)

    // Create sub slices over larger slice
    a := bs[0:2]
    b := bs[2:4]
    c := bs[4:6]

    // Attempt to scan each string value into their respective slices
    _, err := fmt.Sscanf(data, "%4x-%4x-%4x", &a, &b, &c)

    fmt.Println(a, b, c)
    return bytes.Join([][]byte{a, b, c}, []byte("")), err
}

func main() {
    d, err := parse("00ff-ff00-00ff")
    fmt.Printf("Value: %+v Error: %v\n", d, err)
}
```